# perlmagick imagemagick error

Tags: perl, imagemagick, perlmagick

My hosting provider has recently upgraded their servers and I am having lots of problems with imagemagick scripts in perl.  My script worked perfectly on the old server but fail on the new one so I have gone back to basics to try and sort out what is going wrong.

The server reports the imagemagick as:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-2 2011-10-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

and the perl module Image::Magick is version 6.72

The following script is saved on my server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );

use Image::Magick;

my $image = Image::Magick->new;

$x = $image -> Set(size=>"200x200");
warn "$x" if "$x";

$x = $image -> ReadImage("canvas:black");
warn "$x" if "$x";

$x = $image -> Draw (
  stroke    => "red",
  primitive => "line",
  points    => "20,20 180,180");
warn "$x" if "$x";

print "Content-type: image/gif\n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
$image -> write ("gif:-");
```

This fails with the following errors:

```
[Sun Oct 23 11:02:32 2011] imtest.pl: Exception 420: no decode delegate for this image format `lack' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532 at www/11/cgi-bin/imtest.pl line 12.
[Sun Oct 23 11:02:32 2011] imtest.pl: Exception 410: no images defined `Draw' @ error/Magick.xs/XS_Image__Magick_Mogrify/7394 at www/11/cgi-bin/imtest.pl line 18.
```

If I change `ReadImage("canvas:black")` to `ReadImage("xc:black")` then the script runs continuously with no output.

My webhost has been great in trying to find a solution but I need to know if I am doing something wrong here, or if there is an installation problem with imagemagick.

Please note I realise the above can be done with other simpler modules but this is just a simple example to determine if the problem is imagemagick or my code!

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Stu

Comment: The problem was with ImageMagick on the server, my webhoster is still unsure how to fix the problem, but limiting ImageMagick to one cpu core in the perl script solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I received similar errors in winxp command line mode with version 6.3.7 of ImageMagick.

I changed the first few lines to this and it worked:

```
my $image = Image::Magick->new(size=>"200x200");
die "Image::Magick->new failed" unless $image;

my $x = $image->Read("xc:black");
warn "$x" if "$x";
```

Comment: thanks, gave that a try but it didn't help unfortunately.  I've been running the script from a unix command line and it seems to be hanging when imagemagick is attempting to create a tmp file, so think this is down to the imagemagick installation on the server :(